# coffeescript 1.7 broke my ember.js computed properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

Given the following coffeescript.

```
App.Whatever = Em.ArrayController.extend
  clean: Em.computed ->
    @get('content').filterBy('clean', true)
  .property 'content'
```

Coffeescript < 1.7 would correctly output:

```
App.Whatever = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  clean: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('content').filterBy('clean', true);
  }).property('content')
});
```

Now Coffeescript 1.7 outputs:

```
 App.Whatever = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  clean: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('content').filterBy('clean', true);
  })
 }).property('content');
```

This seems like a takeaway. Am I missing anything or do I have to rewrite all my computed properties?

[Example](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aApp.Whatever%20=%20Em.ArrayController.extend%0A%20%20clean%3a%20Em.computed%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20@get%28%27content%27%29.filterBy%28%27clean%27,%20true%29%0A%20%20.property%20%27content%27)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the way you were using coffeescript for chained properties was undocumented. I believe the official method for chaining is to use brackets to explicitly define where the property is attached...

```
App.Whatever = Em.ArrayController.extend
  clean: Em.computed( ->
    @get('content').filterBy('clean', true)
  ).property 'content'
```

Alternatively, if you really want to avoid brackets, you could write it like this

```
App.Whatever = Em.ArrayController.extend
  clean:
    Em.computed ->
      @get('content').filterBy('clean', true)
    .property 'content'
```

Both examples above compile to

```
App.Whatever = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  clean: Em.computed(function() {
    return this.get('content').filterBy('clean', true);
  }).property('content')
});
```

---

UPDATE: CoffeeScript 1.7 new feature...

From the docs... `Leading . now closes all open calls, allowing for simpler chaining syntax.`

```
$ 'body'
.click (e) ->
  $ '.box'
  .fadeIn 'fast'
  .addClass '.active'
.css 'background', 'white'
```

Will output...

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
  return $('.box').fadeIn('fast').addClass('.active');
}).css('background', 'white');
```